# How to convert a List to a java.util.ArrayList[String]

Tags: scala

I'm trying to convert Scala `List` to a Java `ArrayList`.

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

val list: java.util.ArrayList[String] = List("hello", "world").asJava
```

It doesn't seem to be working.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `asJava` function returns an object that implements the `java.util.List` interface. This object is backed by your original list. You can find the documentation for this here (check the `seqAsJavaList` function):

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html

If you want an instance of `java.util.ArrayList`, you can create one using the constructor that takes a `Collection`. Like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList
val list = new ArrayList(List("hello", "world").asJava)
```

Answer (score 1):

`asJava` return a `java.util.List`, not an `ArrayList` You can convert to an `ArrayList` using the constructor `ArrayList(c: java.util.Collection[_ <: String)`

```
val list: java.util.ArrayList[String] = new java.util.ArrayList(List("hello", "world").asJava)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
  val list: java.util.ArrayList[String] = new java.util.ArrayList[String]() 
    list.addAll(List("hello", "world").asJava)
```